# How can I find information on Ecovillages?

Tags: balanced-ecosystems, ecovillage

> [Ecovillages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecovillages) are intentional communities with the goal of becoming
>   more socially, economically and ecologically sustainable. Some aim for
>   a population of 50–150 individuals. Larger ecovillages of up to 2,000
>   individuals exist as networks of smaller subcommunities to create an
>   ecovillage model that allows for social networks within a broader
>   foundation of support. Certain ecovillages have grown by the nearby
>   addition of others, not necessarily members, settling on the periphery
>   of the ecovillage and effectively participating in the ecovillage
>   community.

How can I find information on  that are looking to form, looking for new members, or looking for others to trade with so I can support their movement?

Answer (score 11):

[ic.org](http://directory.ic.org/records/?action=search) has a great directory of Intentional Communities with a decent search tool.  I find it to be quite comprehensive, though sometimes **too** comprehensive.  Not all Intentional Communities are Eco-villages (though many are), all Eco-villages are Intentional Communities.

Comment: The Global Ecovillage Network also maintain an ecovillage database including details of whether projects are seeking new members etc. See http://gen.ecovillage.org/en/projects/34/all or http://gen.ecovillage.org/en/projects/map for details.

Answer (score 8):

One way would just be to do a google search for 'Ecovillage' and then examine the websites you find.  Many of them have websites (although not exactly modern websites) that will have information about what they are, where they are, how to become a member, whether they have interns or places for transients to stay.  Many of the bigger and older ones do.  Here are a couple of the more well known ones you may have heard of:

[Dancing Rabbit](http://www.dancingrabbit.org/) is near Rutledge, MO and has a fairly up to date website.  They have a lot of internships and the like.  I've had many friends take classes or do internships there.  Here's what they have to say about learning more about them, from their [about](http://www.dancingrabbit.org/about-dancing-rabbit-ecovillage/) page:

> If you are interested in Dancing Rabbit, you have lots of options:
>   subscribe to our blog, arrange a visit, or come do a work exchange
>   stint. We are actively seeking new members to share our lives and
>   goals. Together we can build our dreams!

[Earthaven](http://www.earthaven.org/) is near Black Mountain, NC and also has a fairly up to date website.  They also seem to be a place of many internships and classes.  I've got some friends who've visited and speak very highly of it.  From Earthaven's [about](http://www.earthaven.org/what-is-earthaven/) page:

> We teach workshops on starting an ecovillage, and designing an
>   ecovillage. See our Calendar for details. For those seeking in-depth
>   information about ecovillages and intentional communities, we offer
>   additional information and for those seeking technical information we
>   offer consultations.

Those are the two I have personal experience with.  Well, that is, aside from the one I live in (shameless plug) which is just getting started:

[Dandelion Village](http://www.dandelionvillage.org) in Bloomington, IN.  We love visitors and often have couch surfers pass through.  But right now we're three houses in a neighborhood attached to ~3 acres of land. We're just getting started building eco-houses and a food forest on the land.  We spent about 3 years getting the city to change the land's zoning to allow us to build on it.  Being in the city we've had to deal with a lot of regulations and politics, which just slow everything down.  Also, sorry about the website.  We're working on it!

If you want to find more, just do that google search and poke around the websites you find.  You can learn a lot that way!

Answer (score 7):

I would definitely take the time to browse this website and its list of projects. It has an INTERNATIONAL list of permaculture projects occuring around the world. While some of the institutions are not technically eco-villages, some of them are very close to taking that form.

http://permacultureglobal.com/projects

Comment: Great resource!

Answer (score 3):

You can check the intentional community forum at "Permies" - a site devoted to permaculture. While the discussion may not be strictly about "eco-villages" - there are many kinds of group living situations discussed -  its all about sustainability and ecological awareness.

http://www.permies.com/forums/f-6/community